# ~/Library/Messages directory no longer accessible on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos-mojave

I used to access the chat.db in this directory via sqlite3 but this obviously no longer works; in addition the directory is no longer accessible as can seen below:
    $ cd ~/Library/Messages
    $ pwd
    /Users/moshe/Library/Messages
    $ ls
    ls: .: Operation not permitted*

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Are you sure this isn't an authority problem of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS Mojave now protects certain locations. You can allow Terminal (and other apps) to access these locations by going to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Full Disk Access`.

See “Full Disk Access” in [Privacy Preferences help](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-privacy-preferences-on-mac-mh32356/10.14/mac).

Answer (score 0):

## Transparency, Consent, and Control in Mojave

macOS Mojave introduced the Transparency, Consent, and Control (TCC) framework. This framework primarily serves to restrict access to specific device capabilities and sensitive user data such as the Messages data directory. To access these protected areas, an application must either possess the appropriate entitlements or be spawned from an application that does.

**Permitting Local Access via Terminal**

To locally access `~/Library/Messages`, you'll need to grant access to `Terminal.app` or your preferred console application:

1. Open `System Preferences`.
2. Go to `Security & Privacy > Privacy` tab.
3. Choose `Full Disk Access` from the left sidebar.
4. Unlock settings by clicking the lock icon at the bottom left (authentication required).
5. Use the '+' button to navigate to `/Applications/Utilities/` and select Terminal. Alternatively, directly drag and drop Terminal from `/Applications/Utilities/` in Finder to the whitelist in the Preferences panel.

**Permitting Access for Remote Users via SSH/SFTP**

To provide remote users with full disk access via SSH:

1. Open `System Preferences`.
2. Head to `Sharing`.
3. Pick `Remote Login` from the left sidebar.
4. Tick the `Allow full disk access for remote users` checkbox on the right.

**Caveats and Notes**

- Granting Full Disk Access merely bypasses TCC's restrictions. Traditional UNIX-level file permissions are still required to access specific files even after enabling this feature. ***However, due to the way the system functions, on certain versions of macOS when you grant yourself Full Disk Access, you grant all users (even unprivileged users) the possibility to read all other users’ data on the disk, including your own***.
- Additional safeguards, such as System Integrity Protection (SIP) and the Signed System Volume, remain active and might prevent modifications to particular files, ensuring system integrity. Nonetheless, these won't affect accessing `~/Library/Messages`.
- MDM solutions empower administrators to deploy configuration profiles shaping the TCC settings on macOS devices. This capability can be used to prohibit users from granting full disk access.
- See additional documentation on [Privacy Preferences](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-privacy-preferences-on-mac-mh32356/10.14/mac) for more information.