# allow full disk access in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, sqlite, jupyter-notebook

trying to connect with the mac imessage file using sqlite in jupyter notebook:
`conn = sqlite3.connect(/Users/user/Library/Messages/chat.db`
But get this error: `OperationalError: unable to open database file`

Met the same error when opening `chat.db` directly in sqlite browser and was fixed by granting full access to sqlite browser. Wonder to which app should I grant full access to so I can connect to the chat.db in `jupyterlab`

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581085/library-messages-directory-no-longer-accessible-on-macos-mojave

Comment: Already allowed terminal with full disk access. No problem using SQLite3 in terminal but the problem remains how to grant access to jupyter notebook.